# jar file not recognized in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I needed a JSON API for Java and this seemed to be the most popular:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

I downloaded the zip from github and the directory structure looks like this:

```
$ ls
CDL.java          JSONArray.java      JSONString.java   README
Cookie.java       JSONException.java  JSONTokener.java  XML.java
CookieList.java   JSONML.java         JSONWriter.java   XMLTokener.java
HTTP.java         JSONObject.java     Kim.java          zip
HTTPTokener.java  JSONStringer.java   Property.java
```

I want to use this JSON API in my java 8 project in eclipse so I create a jar out of it:

```
$ jar cf json-java.jar *.java zip
```

Then I right clicked on project, selected build path > Configure Build Path > Add External Jars and then select the json-java.jar created above.

Problem is when I try to use the following in the project:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

It gives me the error "The import org.json cannot be resolved", so I look in "Referenced Libraries and I notice the json-java.jar doesn't contain any class files or anything. It seems that it didn't import the jar properly:

[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the ZIP file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip). and extract it to get the Jar.

To add this Jar to your build path,

> Right click the Project > Build Path > Configure build path > Select
>   Libraries tab > Click Add External Libraries > Select the Jar file
>   Download

Comment: You know why when running this I get the error: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException ?

Answer (score 0):

What you did was, put all the source files into a jar file.

That is not gonna work. You need to compile the java into class files and then put those in your jar file.

Alternatively, you can download the binary jar from the following location and use that instead.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json